# Programmatically raise a command

Tags: wpf, command

I have a button:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Command="SomeCommand"/>
```

Is there a way to execute the command from source? Calling the click on the button does not help:

```
MyButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

I mean - this does raise the event, but it does not raise the command. Is there something similar to this `RaiseEvent` but just for Command? If there is not - how can I instantiate `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs`? Is it possible?

Lastly - please do not tell me how to `avoid` calling the command.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Not sure if you mean:

```
if(MyButton.Command != null){
    MyButton.Command.Execute(null);
}
```

with c#6 and later (as proposed by eirik) there is the short form:

```
Mybutton.Command?.Execute(null);
```

**Update**
As proposed by @Benjol, providing the button's `CommandParameter`-property value can be required in some situations and the addition of it instead of `null` may be considered to be used as the default pattern:

```
Mybutton.Command?.Execute(MyButton.CommandParameter);
```

Comment: Thanks. That is so easy yet I did not manage to think of that!

Comment: That looks so strange. Shouldn't it be `if(MyButton.Command != null)`?

Comment: @eirik: Thx, I added it to the answer

Comment: To cover the generic case, consider passing `MyButton.CommandParameter` instead of `null`...

Comment: you're skipping CanExecute

Answer (score 11):

Or if you don't have access to the UI element you can call the static command directly. For example I have a system wide key hook in `App.xaml` and wanted to call my play/pause/stop etc media events:

```
CustomCommands.PlaybackPlayPause.Execute(null, null);
```

passing 2nd parameter as null will call all attached elements.

Answer (score 7):

You need `ICommand.Execute(object)` to accomplish that.

Working example for your sample code: `this.MyButton.Command.Execute(null);`

Answer (score 7):

My prefered way to do it is to do as Sean Sexton recommend in [Executing a Command Programmatically](http://wpf.2000things.com/2014/05/23/1079-executing-a-command-programmatically/)

In short, find the command, check if it can execute and if so, execute.

Example:

```
    if (ApplicationCommands.Open.CanExecute(null, null))
        ApplicationCommands.Open.Execute(null, null);
```

**Why I think it is better:**
I think it's the best way because it will really use the proper path and you do not depends on naming any control. Also, although you know now that you don't use "CanExecute", you never know when somebody will add a behavior for it in the future.